# draggable interaction broken on Firefox for Android after page scroll

Tags: javascript, android, firefox, draggable

I'm working on a javascript draggable interaction that has to work with both mouse and touch input and **does not have any dependencies**. So far it works fine on desktops and mobiles.

***Except Firefox for Android shows the following behaviour:***

- page is not scrolled: fine
- page is scrolled vertically: element can only be dragged horizontally
- page is scrolled horizontally: element can only be dragged vertically
- page is scrolled both vertically and horizontally: element can't be
  dragged at all
- scroll page back to the very top and left: element can be dragged as
  expected again

The code:

```
var evtStart, evtMove, evtEnd;
if ('ontouchend' in window) {
    evtStart = 'touchstart';
    evtMove  = 'touchmove';
    evtEnd   = 'touchend';
} else {
    evtStart = 'mousedown';
    evtMove  = 'mousemove';
    evtEnd   = 'mouseup';
}

// BASIC DRAGGABLE INTERACTION
// No further configuration, just drags ....
var panel = document.querySelector('.testpanel');

panel.addEventListener(evtStart, function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var styles = window.getComputedStyle(panel),
        left   = parseFloat(styles.left),       // css left on mousedown
        top    = parseFloat(styles.top),        // css top on mousedown
        psx    = e.pageX || e.touches[0].pageX, // pointer x on mousedown
        psy    = e.pageY || e.touches[0].pageY; // pointer y on mousedown

    // function actually draging the elmt
    var drag = function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var pmx = e.pageX || e.touches[0].pageX,    // current pointer x while pointer moves
            pmy = e.pageY || e.touches[0].pageY;    // current pointer y while pointer moves

        panel.style.left = left + (pmx - psx) + 'px';   // set new css left of elmt
        panel.style.top  = top  + (pmy - psy) + 'px';   // set new css top of elmt

    };

    panel.addEventListener(evtMove, drag);

    panel.addEventListener(evtEnd, function () {
        panel.removeEventListener(evtMove, drag);
    });
});
```

[Demo page](http://alpha.jspanel.de/dragtest.html)

Again, it works fine on desktop and mobiles except FF for Android.

Why does it not work on FF for Android? Is it something in my code or is it a bug in FF? So far I could not find anything helpful.

I would greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

***Finally I found it myself:***

Just swap **pageX/pageY** with **clientX/clientY** and it works in FF for Android as well.

I guess the implementation in FF for Android is somewhat different, pageX/pageY are not finalized standards yet according to MDN.